# Javascript SDK - Get Trigger Details which associated with AWS Lambda Using getPolicy method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-javascript-sdk

Inside AWS Lambda console if you click on Triggers tab it will show you list of triggers if any triggers are configured for that lambda function.

Lambda trigger information screenshot:

[image]

I am using below code to fetch information using getPolicy function:

```
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});

var params = {
    FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:'+region+':'+AccountId+':function:'+functionName
};

let lambdaFunctionResponse = await lambda.getPolicy(params).promise();
```

getting below response:

{"Version":"2012-10-17","Id":"default","Statement":[{"Sid":"terraform-20944552200000021","Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service":"s3.amazonaws.com"},"Action":"lambda:InvokeFunction","Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:44637832780:function:user-audit-acknowledgement","Condition":{"ArnLike":{"AWS:SourceArn":"arn:aws:s3:::user-data-bucket"}}}]}

but not getting Prefix / Notification name fields

How to get this fields using Javascript SDK for AWS?

Thanks.